# The limits of a definite integral using Mean Value theorem

Tags: integration, riemann-integration, mean-value-theorem

Show that: $$ -\frac{1}{2} < \int_0^1 \frac {x^3 cos 5x}{2+x^2} dx <\frac{1}{2}. $$
I have started by proving that for any two integrable functions $f, g$ defined on $R[a,b]$ such that $f>g$ on $ [a,b]$ if at any $c\in\ [a,b]$ $f$ and $g$ are continuous and $f(c) > g(c)$ then $$ \int_a^b f(x) dx > \int_a^b g(x) dx .$$
I also tried to use the fact that $$ |cos5x| <1.$$ How do I proceed from here? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're on the right track. $$\left|\int_0^1 \frac {x^3 \cos 5x}{2+x^2} dx \right| \leq \int_0^1 \left|\frac {x^3 \cos 5x}{2+x^2} \right|dx < \int_0^1 \frac {1}{2} dx $$

Comment: Thank you for the help. But I have a little question. Shouldn't the bound on left hand side be 0 because x is taken over [0,1]?

Comment: The absolute value of the integral is less than $\frac 1 2$, so the integral itself is between $-\frac 1 2$ and $\frac 1 2$.